# ActiveX / COM object event handler for Hardware Device

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, com, dom-events, activex

I am creating an `ActiveX` control for a hardware *(card swiper)* device. I have understanding of `ActiveX` development and working, but I am little stuck with my specific scenario. Device SKD *(dll files)* have method to activate swiper/chip reader in order to be in listening state. Assume the following:

```
SDK sdk = new SDK();
sdk.RegisterCallback(GlobalCallback);
sdk.ActivateSwiper();

public void GlobalCallback(op, .., ..)
{
   switch(op) {
     case Swiped:
       readCardData();
       break;
     case TransactionData:
       readData();
       break;
     //. . . . 
}
```

Above code is just for example. SDK has a global callback method for any event triggered through device *(eg, card swiped, ICC seated, etc)*. If the SDK is being used in WPF/WinForm app, it is super easy get it working. But in my case, I must need to handle the raised event in `javascript` on my web page.

So, I have exposed a method in ActiveX to turn on the device, which works perfect:

```
[Guid("4794D615-BE51-4a1e-B1BA-453F6E9337C4")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComEvents))]
public class MyComObject : IComObject
{
   [ComVisible(true)]
   public string ActivateDevice()
   {
      SDK sdk = new SDK();
      sdk.RegisterCallback(GlobalCallback);
      string resultCode = sdk.ActivateSwiper();
      return resultCode;
   }
   //. .  <other code> . . .
}
```

and use it in webpage as:

```
<object id="myComComponent" name="myComComponent" classid="clsid:4794D615-BE51-4a1e-B1BA-453F6E9337C4"></object>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var returnCode = myComComponent.ActivateDevice(); //or by creating ActiveXObject
</script
```

I have also got the idea about how to handle events using `ActiveX` on webpage. I learnt it from [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including). But the event is handled by calling the exposed method to raise event. And in my case, when card is swiped, the call will go to `GlobalCallback()` method.

**Questioins:**

- Is there any workaround, I can implement handler in my scenario, to make it usable on javascript?
- I am thinking of something like `PropertyChanged` event, bound to a string property, which holds the derived card data. and the handlers returns this property value. Is there any workaround possible like this? I need little help with this.

I am thinking this as:

```
 public static string CARD_DATA;
 public void GlobalCallback(op, .., ..)
 {
    switch(op) {
      case Swiped:
        CARD_DATA = readCardData();
        //and CARD_DATA is bound to property-changed event, and its handler returns its value.
        //other code
```

Is this even possible? If so, What to be exposed? and How to use it? as this property will be changed internally, when card is swiped, and `case Swiped:` is executed. Is there any workaround?

*Other Info:*

- Web App is MVC 4 famework based
- Device is [The Augusta (IDTech)](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/swipe-reader-writers/the-augusta-an-emv-l1-l2-chip-and-magstripe-reader). *(they don't have actieX/plugin for web)*